Ilumination not working in shader preview
I have problem with the shader preview, none illumination is being reflected, even the HDRI don´t work, just the lamp work at the scene.
The curve at the image has an emission shader, but it´s not reflected at the cube, the second image reflect the cube just because of lamp.
How can I fix it?
 

The Material preview uses Eevee, in Eevee you won't see any light reflected from an Emission material, unless you use a Light Probe > Volume. The HDRI should enlight the scene though, but not the one you may have chosen for your World, it is the default ones that will be used, check the Viewport Shading panel

You have disabled the checkbox Scene World in the Viewport Shading menu. Be sure to enable that in Material Preview, if you want to use your custom world in material preview.

@moonboots I tried to use the Light Probe, but yet it doesn´t work, also I active scene world, but the world is dark anyway :( I don´t have GPU, could that be?

@lajawi I active scene world, but the world is dark yet, what can I do? I downloaded the 3.2 version, and the HDRI background works, but in this version it doesn´t

Could you please share your file?
